# Does stability imply uniqueness for PDE/ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, stability-theory

If given some PDE, which has two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, where $u_1$ corresponds to initial condition $Φ_1$, $u_2$ corresponds to initial condition $Φ_2$, and $|u_1-u_2|$ depends on $|Φ_1-Φ_2|$ continuously, then, given an initial condition (for which the PDE has *a* solution), this PDE has a unique solution right?

Comment: If you have some PDE or ODE which does not have a unique solution, how can you define stability in the first place? You're saying that the solution's behaviour depends continuously on the initial data but which solution do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, perhaps I shall restate my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stability estimate of the form $|u_1 - u_2| \le f(|\Phi_1 - \Phi_2|)$ with $f(0)=0$, then $\Phi_1 = \Phi_2$ implies $|u_1 - u_2| \le 0$ so $u_1 = u_2,$ i.e. the solution is unique.